# I'm trying to scrape the color and model of the product from this link

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm getting error here I was not able to scrape a data.

base url = https://www.mobilephonesdirect.co.uk/brands/apple?monthly_cost=40

product url = https://www.mobilephonesdirect.co.uk/handset/apple/iphone-12

I want to get memory details from all the product links.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UglM0.png)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xlwt
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.mobilephonesdirect.co.uk/brands')
time.sleep(5)
cookies = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Accept')]")
time.sleep(5)
cookies.click()
time.sleep(5)
print("cookies accepted")
time.sleep(5)
driver.maximize_window()
print("window maximized")
click = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.u-grid--3--bp-medium:nth-child(1) .u-ai--center').click()
time.sleep(5)
print("clicked apple phones")
time.sleep(5)
#creating soup obj for the products
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'html.parser')
#print(soup.prettify())
#creating obj for apple product link
print(driver.current_url)
links = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'o-flex-container u-px--xsmall u-pt--xsmall'})
list_links = []
for link in links:
    anchor = link.find('a')
    url = 'https://www.mobilephonesdirect.co.uk' + anchor["href"]
    list_links.append(url)
for urls in list_links:
    driver.get(urls)
    #print(soup1.prettify())
    print(driver.current_url)
    source = driver.page_source
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(source,'html.parser')

    product_memory = soup1.find('div',{'class':'u-fz--title-small u-fw--400'})
    print(product_memory.text)
```

Comment: This issue can be handle by debugging, i think so. Please try to set break point and debug.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that it's running a little bit too quickly in one place.

After this line:

```
driver.get(urls)
```

Put this

```
time.sleep(5)
```

and then it will work correctly.

I'm not overly familiar with these libraries, but I think what's happening is that the `driver.get(urls)` line tells the webdriver to load that page, but then the next line `source = driver.page_source` runs immediately, so the page hasn't loaded yet. So there's no source yet, because the page hasn't finished loading. Putting that pause in gives enough time for the page to load.